# Design patterns in Assembly language

Tags: design-patterns, assembly

Basically, are there any?

I'm tempted to think they do exist. For example, a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) can be implemented as a series of "jumps", where the target of a jump is specified "externally". Singleton will be just a well-known location in memory/code, etc.

I'm by no means an assembly expert, so these examples might turn out to be completely impossible, but still.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assembly language is more about "tricks" than design patterns. While high-level design patterns can still be thought of and brought into play, most assembly guys are more concerned with clock cycles and exploiting tricks of instructions.

For example, in x86 it is quicker to do `xor eax, eax`, than it is to do `mov eax, 0`.

The point I am making (thanks for the downvotes!) is that with Assembly Language you want to focus more on the minor detail than you do the big design picture. Just as you wouldn't focus on fine details of execution speed in a high level language.

Comment: There is no such thing as "clr eax" on x86. Maybe you wanted to say "mov eax, 0"?

Comment: Thanks Phil, it's been along time since I was down at the metal.

Answer (score 7):

First definition on Google: "a design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design".

By that standard I'd say they most definitely exist.

First one that springs to mind is a jump table.

Answer (score 2):

Applicable to OO design patterns:

People usually implement higher level language constructs like inheritance polymorphism and use them as building blocks to implement their intentions in design patterns. But then, maybe it's easier to find a c or c++ compiler for the platform and use design patterns without hassle of implementing basic oo functionality.

Comment: Design patterns are not specific to OOP, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no design patterns for all the layers then you should think about design patents.
Because saying "i just write the code to the very details" is false modesty for "there are so much details to handle that the industrialisation of the software engineering process is too clever to fit this narrow stackoverflow".

Comment: Did you really mean to say to think about "patents" instead of "patterns"?  Or did you mean you *should* think about patterns?

Answer (score 0):

A possible example would be how to write a loop: [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump)

Or SIMD vectorizing something idempotent (like a `memcpy` with non-overlapping src, dst) using an unaligned first and last vector, and aligned vectors for the main loop body.  If the alignment and/or sizes aren't all multiples of 16 bytes, there's partial overlap, but that's fine.