# Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?

Tags: performance, loops, assembly, optimization, micro-optimization

When trying to understand assembly (with compiler optimization on), I see this behavior:

A very basic loop like this

```c
outside_loop;
while (condition) {
     statements;
}
```

Is often compiled into (pseudocode)

```
    ; outside_loop
    jmp loop_condition    ; unconditional
loop_start:
    loop_statements
loop_condition:
    condition_check
    jmp_if_true loop_start
    ; outside_loop
```

However, if the optimization is not turned on, it compiles to normally understandable code:

```
loop_condition:
    condition_check
    jmp_if_false loop_end
    loop_statements
    jmp loop_condition  ; unconditional
loop_end:
```

According to my understanding, the compiled code is better resembled by this:

```c
goto condition;
do {
    statements;
    condition:
}
while (condition_check);
```

I can't see a huge performance boost or code readability boost, so why is this often the case? Is there a name for this loop style, for example "trailing condition check"?

Comment: On this topic I recommend reading Agner Fog's [optimizing assembly](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf) . In particular section 12 (page 89) about **loops**. The idea was to eliminate the unconditional jump inside the loop.

Comment: Hm, also the `loop_start:` can be aligned w/o executing the filling `nops` behind the `jmp`. Although that's hardly critical selling point, in cases where loop repeats enough time 1-2 `nop`s to align unoptimized kind of code wouldn't hurt measurably.

Comment: @Ped7g: It's not worth jumping over one or two long-NOP instructions on modern x86.  And loop alignment is rarely needed on modern x86 CPUs anyway.

Comment: readability of the generated assembly is of no concern to the compiler. And what little concern there is it goes exclusively into comments, not in the code generation.

Comment: You cannot see a huge performance boost you say. Well, have you measured it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Related: asm loop basics: [While, Do While, For loops in Assembly Language (emu8086)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665528/while-do-while-for-loops-in-assembly-language-emu8086)

Terminology: Wikipedia says "[loop inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_inversion)" is the name for turning a `while(x)` into `if(x) do{}while(x)`, putting the condition at the bottom of the loop where it belongs.

---

**Fewer instructions / uops inside the loop = better**.  Structuring the code outside the loop to achieve this is very often a good idea.

Sometimes this requires "loop rotation" (peeling part of the first iteration so the actual loop body has the conditional branch at the bottom).  So you do some of the first iteration and maybe skip the loop entirely, then fall into the loop.  Sometimes you also need some code after the loop to finish the last iteration.

Sometimes loop rotation is extra useful if the last iteration is a special case, e.g. a store you need to skip.  This lets you implement a `while(1) {... ; if(x)break; ...; }` loop as a do-while, or put one of the conditions of a multiple-condition loop at the bottom.

Some of these optimizations are related to or enable software pipelining, e.g. loading something for the next iteration.  (OoO exec on x86 makes SW pipelining not very important these days but it's still useful for in-order cores like many ARM.  And unrolling with multiple accumulators is still very valuable for hiding loop-carried FP latency in a reduction loop like a dot product or sum of an array.)

**`do{}while()` is the canonical / idiomatic structure for loops in asm on all architectures, get used to it.**  IDK if there's a name for it; I would say such a loop has a "do while structure".  If you want names, you could call the `while()` structure "crappy unoptimized code" or "written by a novice". :P  Loop-branch at the bottom is universal, and not even worth mentioning as a [Loop Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization).  You *always* do that.

This pattern is so widely used that on CPUs that use static branch prediction for branches without an entry in the branch-predictor caches, unknown forward conditional branches are predicted not-taken, unknown backwards branches are predicted taken (because they're probably loop branches).  See [Static branch prediction on newer Intel processors](https://xania.org/201602/bpu-part-one) on Matt Godbolt's blog, and Agner Fog's branch-prediction chapter at the start of his microarch PDF.

This answer ended up using x86 examples for everything, but much of this applies across the board for all architectures.  I wouldn't be surprised if other superscalar / out-of-order implementations (like some ARM, or POWER) also have limited branch-instruction throughput whether they're taken or not.  But fewer instructions inside the loop is nearly universal when all you have is a conditional branch at the bottom, and no unconditional branch.

---

**If the loop might need to run zero times**, compilers more often put a test-and-branch outside the loop to skip it, instead of jumping to the loop condition at the bottom.  (i.e. if the compiler can't prove the loop condition is always true on the first iteration).

BTW, [this paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Eecj2122/research/x86_loop_optimizations/x86_loop_optimizations.pdf) calls transforming `while()` to `if(){ do{}while; }` an "inversion", but loop inversion usually means inverting a nested loop.  (e.g. if the source loops over a row-major multi-dimensional array in the wrong order, a clever compiler could change `for(i) for(j) a[j][i]++;` into `for(j) for(i) a[j][i]++;` if it can prove it's correct.)  But I guess you can look at the `if()` as a zero-or-one iteration loop.  Fun fact, compiler devs teaching their compilers how to invert a loop (to allow auto-vectorization) for a (very) specific case is [why SPECint2006's libquantum benchmark is "broken"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=SPECint&oldid=927463790#Critique).  Most compilers can't invert loops in the general case, just ones that looks almost exactly like the one in SPECint2006...

---

You can help the compiler make more compact asm (fewer instructions outside the loop) by writing `do{}while()` loops in C when you know the caller isn't allowed to pass `size=0` or whatever else guarantees a loop runs at least once.

(Actually 0 or negative for signed loop bounds.  Signed vs. unsigned loop counters is a tricky optimization issue, especially if you choose a narrower type than pointers; check your compiler's asm output to make sure it isn't sign-extending a narrow loop counter inside the loop very time if you use it as an array index.  But note that signed can actually be helpful, because the compiler can assume that `i++ <= bound` will eventually become false, [because signed overflow is UB](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) but unsigned isn't.  So with unsigned, `while(i++ <= bound)` is infinite if `bound = UINT_MAX`.)  I don't have a blanket recommendation for when to use signed vs. unsigned;  `size_t` is often a good choice for looping over arrays, though, but if you want to avoid the x86-64 REX prefixes in the loop overhead (for a trivial saving in code size) but convince the compiler not to waste any instructions zero or sign-extending, it can be tricky.

---

> I can't see a huge performance boost

Here's an example where that optimization will give speedup of 2x on Intel CPUs before Haswell, because P6 and SnB/IvB can only run branches on port 5, including not-taken conditional branches.

Required background knowledge for this static performance analysis: [Agner Fog's microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) (read the Sandybridge section).  Also read his Optimizing Assembly guide, it's excellent.  (Occasionally outdated in places, though.)  See also other x86 performance links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.  See also [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770) for some static analysis backed up by experiments with perf counters, and some explanation of fused vs. unfused domain uops.

You could also use Intel's [IACA software (Intel Architecture Code Analyzer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021337/what-is-iaca-and-how-do-i-use-it) to do static analysis on these loops.

```
; sum(int []) using SSE2 PADDD (dword elements)
; edi = pointer,  esi = end_pointer.
; scalar cleanup / unaligned handling / horizontal sum of XMM0 not shown.

; NASM syntax
ALIGN 16          ; not required for max performance for tiny loops on most CPUs
.looptop:                 ; while (edi<end_pointer) {
    cmp     edi, esi    ; 32-bit code so this can macro-fuse on Core2
    jae    .done            ; 1 uop, port5 only  (macro-fused with cmp)
    paddd   xmm0, [edi]     ; 1 micro-fused uop, p1/p5 + a load port
    add     edi, 16         ; 1 uop, p015
    jmp    .looptop         ; 1 uop, p5 only

                            ; Sandybridge/Ivybridge ports each uop can use
.done:                    ; }
```

This is 4 total fused-domain uops ([with macro-fusion of the `cmp/jae`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771526/x86-64-assembly-loop-conditions-and-out-of-order/31778403)), so it can issue from the front-end into the out-of-order core at one iteration per clock.  But in the unfused domain there are 4 ALU uops and Intel pre-Haswell only has 3 ALU ports.

More importantly, port5 pressure is the bottleneck: **This loop can execute at only one iteration per 2 cycles** because cmp/jae and jmp both need to run on port5.  Other uops stealing port5 could reduce practical throughput somewhat below that.

**Writing the loop idiomatically for asm**, we get:

```
ALIGN 16
.looptop:                 ; do {
    paddd   xmm0, [edi]     ; 1 micro-fused uop, p1/p5 + a load port
    add     edi, 16         ; 1 uop, p015

    cmp     edi, esi        ; 1 uop, port5 only  (macro-fused with cmp)
    jb    .looptop        ; } while(edi < end_pointer);
```

Notice right away, independent of everything else, that this is one fewer instruction in the loop.  This loop structure is at least slightly better on everything from simple non-pipelined 8086 through [classic RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) (like early MIPS), especially for long-running loops (assuming they don't bottleneck on memory bandwidth).

**Core2 and later should run this at one iteration per clock**, twice as fast as the `while(){}`-structured loop, if memory isn't a bottleneck (i.e. assuming L1D hits, or at least L2 actually; this is only SSE2 16-bytes per clock).

This is only 3 fused-domain uops, so can issue at better than one per clock on anything since Core2, or just one per clock if issue groups always end with a taken branch.

But the important part is that port5 pressure is vastly reduced: only `cmp/jb` needs it.  The other uops will probably be scheduled to port5 some of the time and steal cycles from loop-branch throughput, but this will be a few % instead of a factor of 2.  See [How are x86 uops scheduled, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681331/how-are-x86-uops-scheduled-exactly).

Most CPUs that normally have a taken-branch throughput of one per 2 cycles can still execute tiny loops at 1 per clock.  There are some exceptions, though.  (I forget which CPUs can't run tight loops at 1 per clock; maybe Bulldozer-family?  Or maybe just some low-power CPUs like VIA Nano.)  Sandybridge and Core2 can definitely run tight loops at one per clock.  They even have loop buffers; Core2 has a loop buffer after instruction-length decode but before regular decode.  Nehalem and later recycle uops in the queue that feeds the issue/rename stage.  (Except on Skylake with microcode updates; Intel had to disable the loop buffer because of a partial-register merging bug.)

However, there is **a loop-carried dependency chain** on `xmm0`: Intel CPUs have 1-cycle latency `paddd`, so we're right up against that bottleneck, too.  `add esi, 16` is also 1 cycle latency.  On Bulldozer-family, even integer vector ops have 2c latency, so that would bottleneck the loop at 2c per iteration.  (AMD since K8 and Intel since SnB can run two loads per clock, so we need to unroll anyway for max throughput.)    With floating point, you *definitely* want to unroll with multiple accumulators.  [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction).

---

If I'd used an indexed addressing mode, like `paddd xmm0, [edi + eax]`, I could have used `sub eax, 16` / `jnc` at the loop condition.  SUB/JNC can macro-fuse on Sandybridge-family, but the indexed load [would un-laminate on SnB/IvB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes) (but stay fused on Haswell and later, unless you use the AVX form).

```
    ; index relative to the end of the array, with an index counting up towards zero
    add   rdi, rsi          ; edi = end_pointer
    xor   eax, eax
    sub   eax, esi          ; eax = -length, so [rdi+rax] = first element

 .looptop:                  ; do {
    paddd   xmm0, [rdi + rax]
    add     eax, 16
    jl    .looptop          ; } while(idx+=16 < 0);  // or JNC still works
```

(It's usually better to unroll some to hide the overhead of pointer increments instead of using indexed addressing modes, especially for stores, partly because indexed stores can't use the port7 store AGU on Haswell+.)

On Core2/Nehalem `add/jl` don't macro-fuse, so this is 3 fused-domain uops even in 64-bit mode, without depending on macro-fusion.  Same for AMD K8/K10/Bulldozer-family/Ryzen: no fusion of the loop condition, but PADDD with a memory operand is 1 m-op / uop.

On SnB, `paddd` un-laminates from the load, but add/jl macro-fuse, so again 3 fused-domain uops.  (But in the unfused domain, only 2 ALU uops + 1 load, so probably fewer resource conflicts reducing throughput of the loop.)

On HSW and later, this is 2 fused-domain uops because an indexed load can stay micro-fused with PADDD, and `add/jl` macro-fuses.  (Predicted-taken branches run on port 6, so there are never resource conflicts.)

Of course, the loops can only run at best 1 iteration per clock because of taken branch throughput limits even for tiny loops.  This indexing trick is potentially useful if you had something else to do inside the loop, too.

---

#### But all of these loops had no unrolling

Yes, that exaggerates the effect of loop overhead.  *But* gcc doesn't unroll by default even at `-O3` (unless it decides to *fully* unroll).  It only unrolls with profile-guided optimization to let it know which loops are hot.  (`-fprofile-use`).  You can enable `-funroll-all-loops`, but I'd only recommend doing that on a per-file basis for a compilation unit you know has one of your hot loops that needs it.  Or maybe even on a per-function basis with an `__attribute__`, if there is one for optimization options like that.

So this is highly relevant for compiler-generated code.  (But `clang` does default to unrolling tiny loops by 4, or small loops by 2, and extremely importantly, using multiple accumulators to hide latency.)

---

#### Benefits with very low iteration count:

Consider what happens when the loop body should run once or twice:  There's a lot more jumping with anything other than `do{}while`.

- For `do{}while`, execution is a straight-line with no taken branches and one not-taken branch at the bottom.  This is excellent.
- For an `if() { do{}while; }` that might run the loop zero times, it's two not-taken branches.  That's still very good.  (Not-taken is slightly cheaper for the front-end than taken when both are correctly predicted).
- For a jmp-to-the-bottom `jmp; do{}while()`, it's one taken unconditional branch, one taken loop condition, and then the loop branch is not-taken.  This is kinda clunky but modern branch predictors are very good...
- For a `while(){}` structure, this is one not-taken loop exit, one taken `jmp` at the bottom, then one taken loop-exit branch at the top.

With more iterations, each loop structure does one more taken branch.  `while(){}` also does one more not-taken branch per iteration, so it quickly becomes obviously worse.

The latter two loop structures have more jumping around for small trip counts.

---

Jumping to the bottom also has a disadvantage for non-tiny loops that the bottom of the loop might be cold in L1I cache if it hasn't run for a while.  Code fetch / prefetch is good at bringing code to the front-end in a straight line, but if prediction didn't predict the branch early enough, you might have a code miss for the jump to the bottom.  Also, parallel decode will probably have (or could have) decoded some of the top of the loop while decoding the `jmp` to the bottom.

Conditionally jumping over a `do{}while` loop avoids all that: you only jump forwards into code that hasn't been run yet in cases where the code you're jumping over shouldn't run at all.  It often predicts very well because a lot of code never actually takes 0 trips through the loop.  (i.e. it could have been a `do{}while`, the compiler just didn't manage to prove it.)

Jumping to the bottom also means the core can't start working on the real loop body until after the front-end chases two taken branches.

There are cases with complicated loop conditions where it's easiest to write it this way, and the performance impact is small, but compilers often avoid it.

---

#### Loops with multiple exit conditions:

Consider a `memchr` loop, or a `strchr` loop: they have to stop at the end of the buffer (based on a count) or the end of an implicit-length string (0 byte).  But they also have to `break` out of the loop if they find a match before the end.

So you'll often see a structure like

```
do {
    if () break;

    blah blah;
} while(condition);
```

Or just two conditions near the bottom.  Ideally you can test multiple logical conditions with the same actual instruction (e.g. `5 < x && x < 25` using `sub eax, 5` / `cmp eax, 20` / `ja .outside_range`, unsigned compare trick for range checking, or combine that with an `OR` to [check for alphabetic characters of either case in 4 instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932273/how-to-access-a-char-array-and-change-lower-case-letters-to-upper-case-and-vice/35936844#35936844)) but sometimes you can't and just need to use an `if()break` style loop-exit branch as well as a normal backwards taken branch.

---

## Further reading:

- Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) for good ways to look at compiler output (e.g. what kind of inputs give interesting output, and a primer on reading x86 asm for beginners).  related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)
- [Modern Microprocessors A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/).  Details look at superscalar pipelined CPUs, mostly architecture neutral.  Very good.  Explains instruction-level parallelism and stuff like that.
- [Agner Fog's x86 optimization guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) and microarch pdf.  This will take you from being able to write (or understand) correct x86 asm to being able to write *efficient* asm (or see what the compiler should have done).
- other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, including Intel's optimization manuals.  Also several of my answers (linked in the tag wiki) have things that Agner missed in his testing on more recent microarchitectures (like un-lamination of micro-fused indexed addressing modes on SnB, and partial register stuff on Haswell+).
- [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction): how to use multiple accumulators to hide latency of a reduction loop (like an FP dot product).
- [Lecture 7: Loop Transformations](https://www.slidedoc.us/download/documents/7-loopoptimizations) (also [on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517030057/http://users.ices.utexas.edu/%7Elenharth/cs378/fall14/8%20-%20LoopOptimizations.pdf)).  Lots of cool stuff that compilers do to loops, using C syntax to describe the asm.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization

Sort of off topic:

- Memory bandwidth is almost always important, but it's not widely known that a single core on most modern x86 CPUs can't saturate DRAM, and [not even close on many-core Xeons where single-threaded bandwidth is *worse* than on a quad-core with dual channel memory controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260020/why-is-skylake-so-much-better-than-broadwell-e-for-single-threaded-memory-throug/47787231#47787231).
- [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory/47714514#47714514) (my answer has commentary on what's changed and what's still relevant in  Ulrich Drepper's well-known excellent article.)

Comment: If anyone finds this version of the answer too "dense" or full of side-notes, [the first version of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47790760/1) has the core stuff that directly answers the question (still with examples + static analysis).  It gets to the point quicker than the current version.

Comment: TIL that gcc doesn't unroll loops by default. I does seem to unroll in some scenarios though, such as nested loops and vectorization. It's kind of too bad because especially with vectorization you end up with things like a giant prologue and a giant epilogue and then a small not-unrolled loop body. So the code size is huge but all for the benefit of the part that is executed at most once.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: gcc *really* needs to learn when it can use an unaligned (possibly overlapping) first vector instead of a scalar intro.  Especially with wider vectors, it can be all-scalar up to fairly large counts.  IDK if there's a missed-optimization bug for this already open.

Comment: Or failing that at least into and outro loops rather than fully unrolled stuff that often runs into 100s of instructions. Admittedly that's a space/time tradeoff - but gcc is already effectively staking a position on that spectrum by not unrolling loops, so it is pretty inconsistent to at the same time generate giant intos and/or outros.

Comment: This has got the be the longest answer I have ever come across on the stack exchange....

Comment: @Hackstaar: This one didn't even hit the 30k char limit :P, unlike [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355466) / [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37362225) / [Memory-constrained external sorting of strings, with duplicates combined&counted, on a critical server (billions of filenames)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32535222)